# C++ How can i delete a class with a pointer of class in an array and make array [num] be nullptr?

Tags: c++

How can i delete a class with a pointer of class in an array and make array [num] be nullptr? Any way is fine.

```
class x
{
    //stuff
};
class y
{
   x* xptr = new x();
   std::vector<x*> xptrarray;
   void thing()
   {
        xptrarray.push_back(xptr);
        //how can i delete x and make xptrarray[0] = nullptr;
        //i managed to delete it with 
        delete xptrarray[0]
        //but i cant make it nullptr
        xptrarray[0] = nullptr // gives Access violation writing location error
   }
};
```

stuff i tried:

```
x* tempPixelPtr = xptrarray[0];
xptrarray[0] = nullptr;
delete tempPtr; // i dont know why, it just didnt get deleted, probably because it's a pointer that points to another pointer. I'm not sure though.
```

```
xptrarray[0] = nullptrr; // even though it is not in list, it somehow still exists and code in it runs.
```

Sorry if it is something simple i didnt realized.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve], the first example should work apart from the missing semicolons.

Comment: Before you go further with pointers and deleting xptrarrays have a look here : 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii
This is one of the most important concepts in C++ to learn. Manage resources (like memory new/delete) with the lifecycle of objects :)

Comment: To give you an idea how you can write C++ without having to use pointers for everything I made this example : https://godbolt.org/z/MhEhP51bf

Comment: For modern C++, I consider the use of `new` and `delete` to be a very advanced topic, and something that shouldn't be used until you have at least a couple years of experience.  Instead, use containers like `std::vector` and smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr`, and as a last resort if really really really needed `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @t.niese u r right. I have deleted the whole comment.

Comment: You should genreally use `std::vector<x>` (for small `x`) or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<x>>` (for large `x`). Manual memory managment is very error prone. By the way, your problem is probably in code not shown.